# Collection type of GC in Oracle or OpenJDK is precise or conservative?

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, java, oraclejdk

I need to know what type of collector does GC of Oracle and OpenJDK uses, is it precise collector or conservative collector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HotSpot JVM implements type-accurate garbage collection - as does the IBM JVM.

Comment: is it kind of precise collector?

Comment: type-accurate means precise, yes